# Solution to the heat equation

Tags: probability, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, heat-equation

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N} (0, I_n)$ be a standard gaussian in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y$ be a another random variable with a smooth density $f$. I want to show that for $s>0$, the density of $Y + \sqrt{s} X$ (say $f_s$) is a solution to the heat equation, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial s} f_s (x) = \frac{1}{2} \Delta f_s(x)$$

I'm not sure how to proceed as I have difficulty finding $f_s$.  Any help?

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution of $Z=Y+\sqrt{s}X$ is the following
$$f_Z(z,s)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\phi(z-y,s)f(y)dy, \ \ z \in \mathbb{R}^n,s \in [0,T]$$
where $f$ is the density of $Y$ and $\phi(x,s)$ is the density of a multivariate normal with covariance matrix $s\mathbf{I}_n$.This is the solution to the PDE
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial s}f_Z(z,s)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z_k^2}f_Z(z,s)$$
with initial condition $f_Z(z,0)=f(z)$. This is because the fundamental solution to the PDE is a multivariate normal density with covariance matrix $s\mathbf{I}_n$, so the particular solution is given by the [convolution with the given initial condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Fundamental_solutions)

---

Note: I assumed $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

---

It can be shown that the convolution is a solution by using the theory of Brownian motions. Consider a Brownian motion $W_t \in \mathbb{R}^n$. The evolution of its probability density is described by the $n$-dimensional [Forward Kolmogorov Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_equations)
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f_W(w,t)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial^2}{\partial w_k^2}f_W(w,t)$$
with general initial condition $f_W(w,0)=f(w)$ (which is a starting probability density). The solution is given by the convolution
$$f_W(w,t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\phi(w-y,t)f(y)dy, \ \ w \in \mathbb{R}^n,t \in [0,T]$$
where $\phi(w,t)$ is the density of a multivariate normal with covariance matrix $s\mathbf{I}_n$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this using Brownian motion?

Comment: You're welcome. Do you mean finding the density of $Y+W_s$?

Comment: No I meant is there a way to prove that $f_s$ is a solution without finding the density ; perhaps using the notion of Brownian motion?

Comment: Just a thought. maybe a silly question.

Comment: @Jane added details that might interest you

Comment: Thanks. I will look into that.

Comment: Try not to answer questions when someone dumps one here, like the above, with no effort. Apart from being against [site polixy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/10513), it is more helpful to get them to do some work themselves (which is why people often ask "what have you tried?"). Also, it is not unlikely that this is their assessed homework, so giving them the complete answer is a kick in the teeth to the rest of their class.